# What is the difference between compiling and transpiling?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, programming-languages

I know that transpiling is used for compilation.But there is any difference between compiling and transpiling?

Comment: i guess compiling will in the end create a `runnable` file like `.exe` which will be executed from the OS directly while transpiling is just the convertion from one slang to another (like TypeScript to JavaScript).

Comment: "Transpiling" is a misleading and redundant term that shall never be used.